# Downloading Redux State into an Angular 2 component and then iterating over its result

Tags: angular, redux

I'd like to download an array of objects stored in Redux into an Angular 2 component, and then iterate over each of the array's objects and perform some operation on it, storing its results in the component. An example:

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Store } from '@ngrx/store';
import { AppStore } from './app-store';

@Component({
  selector: 'selector',
  templateUrl: './templateUrl.html'
})
export class Component {

  sum : number = 0;
  arrayFromRedux$;
  
  constructor(
    private store: Store<AppStore>
  ) { 
    this.arrayFromRedux$ = this.store.select('dataFromReduxStore')
    .subscribe(data => this.sum = data.reduce( (a,b) => a.number+ b.number));
  }

}
```

Data from store:

```js
[
  {
    "name": item1,
    "number": 3
  },
  {
    "name": item2,
    "number": 5
  },
  {
    "name": item3,
    "number": 1
  },
]
```

I want sum to equal 9.

Part of the problem I think is that the component receives the data as an observable stream, and there's a complication in iterating over that.

Immediate error I get is a TS error: "[ts] Property 'reduce' does not exist on type '{}'." This comes up in trying to perform reduce operation on data. Have tried variations of this, and haven't come across anything that seems to work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I believe you should subscribe to your observable during ngOnInit. Also, variables ending in $ are usually an observable stream not a subscription.

I had trouble with your data.reduce function so I modified it.

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Store } from '@ngrx/store';
import { AppStore } from './app-store';

@Component({
  selector: 'selector',
  templateUrl: './templateUrl.html'
})
export class Component {

  sum : number = 0;
  arrayFromRedux$;
  mySubsription;
  
  constructor(
    private store: Store<AppStore>
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() { 
    this.arrayFromRedux$ = this.store.select('dataFromReduxStore');
    this.mySubscription = this.arrayFromRedux$
      .subscribe((data: Array<Object>) => this.sum = data.reduce( (acc, item) => acc + item.number, 0);
  }
  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.mySubsription.unsubscribe();
  }

}
```